# Reuse GIT_WORK_TREE in post-receive hook to rm a few files

Tags: git, git-checkout, bash

I've used this 'tutorial' to set up a DSP environment: http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto (Yes, I don't have a T).

My workflow is very easy:

1. Develop locally (**D**)
2. Commit a few things
3. Commit more things
4. Push to Staging (and Github) (**S**)
5. Test new code on Staging
6. Push to Production (**P**)

My code contains CSS files that are minified by my code and then saved to 1 file: `all.css`. Locally, I've turned that option off, so I don't have to manually remove `all.css` all the time every time I change my CSS. On both Staging and Production, they should cache as soon as possible (so create `all.css` from the separate CSS files).

The problem is every time I push, I have to remove `all.css` (and `all.js` -- same exact story) to see the changes (and properly test).

From the tutorial I made a `post-receive` hook that checks out the changes into a certain folder (where Apache reads the code).

My current `post-receive` hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f
```

I want to reuse `$GIT_WORK_TREE` to remove two files within `$GIT_WORK_TREE` (being `www/all.css` and `www/all.js`), but I can't... There's no var $GIT_WORK_TREE on the next line.

So I changed it to this, but I don't like that, especially if I want to do more with it in the future:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f
rm /var/www/www.example.org/www/all.css
rm /var/www/www.example.org/www/all.js
```

`$GIT_WORK_TREE` is NOT reused like this.

**Things I've tried that don't work:**

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f
rm $GIT_WORK_TREE/www/all.css
rm $GIT_WORK_TREE/www/all.js
```

> rm: file doesn't exist etc (/www/all.css) (`$GIT_WORK_TREE` is empty)

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org
git checkout -f
```

> fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org
cd $GIT_WORK_TREE
git checkout -f
```

> fatal: Not in a git repository (or any .....)

I guess my problem is as much with how Bash works as it is with how GIT works =)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are a few problems with that you're trying at the moment.  Perhaps it's best to explain what's wrong with each example you've tried in turn:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f
rm $GIT_WORK_TREE/www/all.css
rm $GIT_WORK_TREE/www/all.js
```

The problem here is that if you define a variable directly before the command, the environment variable is only set in the environment of the command you're running - it's not set in the current shell.  You can easily test this:

```
$ FOO=bar sh -c 'echo $FOO'            
bar
$ echo $FOO

$
```

Your next attempt was:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org
git checkout -f
```

In this case, in order for the variable to be set in the environment of other commands you invoke in the script, you need to export it, for example with `export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org` instead of your first line.

Your last attempt was:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org
cd $GIT_WORK_TREE
git checkout -f
```

This has the same problem as your previous attempt (i.e. that you need to export `GIT_WORK_TREE`) but it also has a more subtle problem.  As I describe in [this blog post](http://longair.net/blog/2011/04/09/missing-git-hooks-documentation/), `GIT_DIR` is set to `.` (i.e. the current directory) in the `post-receive` script's environment.  So, if you change directory to the top of the working tree, `GIT_DIR` will point to that directory, and not the `.git` directory!  A couple of good rules of thumb are (a) that you should only set `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` together, and (b) if you do set them, you should set them both to absolute paths.  So, I think the following hook will work in your case:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org
export GIT_DIR=/var/www/www.example.org/.git
cd $GIT_WORK_TREE
git checkout -f
rm www/all.css
rm www/all.js
```

Comment: Yeah, only my `GIT_DIR` isn't in my `GIT_WORK_TREE`. It's in an entirely different location. I don't think that matters though. I don't have to set `GIT_DIR`. I don't think the `cd` is necessary either. I just didn't know enough about bash to know you have to export a var (crazy!). Now I do =) I'm gonna try this.

Comment: Works like a charm. Without the 2nd `export` and the `cd`.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you've sorted that out.  You're right, if you export `GIT_WORK_TREE` and don't `cd` then you don't need to set `GIT_DIR` either.  I still maintain, however, that the best way to avoid potentially confusing edge cases is to follow the rules of thumb I mentioned above!

Answer (score 7):

why not use a variable for the path?

```
#!/bin/sh
work_tree=/var/www/www.example.org
GIT_WORK_TREE=$work_tree git checkout -f
rm $work_tree/www/all.css
rm $work_tree/www/all.js
```

then you don't need to export.
This works perfect for me.

Comment: Yeah, that's good too. Is exporting bad? What is the exporting anyway? Why is exporting unnecessary if its created on the same line as the git checkout? (I'm a bash noob.)

Answer (score 1):

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=....
export GIT_WORK_TREE
git ...
rm $GIT_WORK_TREE/...
```

should work and is safest (you don't always need to export your environment variables, but usually it doesn't harm :))

Comment: So what would it be literally? I don't understand the line starting with `git ...`. I don't have a line like that.