# Web-based git: how to copy all files except some to webroot?

Tags: git

I have set up git on our webserver in a similar fashion as: http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto

The following post-receive hook is set up:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/ git checkout -f
```

This works fine. However, there are *certain* directories and files that I *do* not want to copy to the webroot, but I do want them in the repository (so .gitignore is not an option). What is a good way to ignore them when checking out? Or should I copy them and then promptly remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was already the same question on Stack Overflow, with a solution: [Reuse GIT_WORK_TREE in post-receive hook to rm a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635018/reuse-git-work-tree-in-post-receive-hook-to-rm-a-few-files)