# git deploy with submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've been looking into different ways of deploying sites using git, and found the following tutorial:

http://42pixels.com/blog/quick-and-dirty-git-deployment

I like the ideas presented in this tutorial, and would be keen on using it for my sites, only it doesn't seem to support submodules.

Is there anyway that this can be changed so that submodules are also pulled in and updated as required?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I've been working on this problem for the last couple of hours, and I seem to be making progress, but I still can't get it working.

I've switched to this tutorial: http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto (which is mostly the same, just a few slight changes), and after following some advice found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6636509/1049688 I've ended up with a post-receive file that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

export GIT_WORK_TREE=/srv/www/limeblast.co.uk/htdocs_test
export GIT_DIR=/srv/www/limeblast.co.uk/.git
cd $GIT_WORK_TREE

git checkout -f master
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

This all seems fine in theory, and it would appear that the submodule commands are running, but I'm getting the following error messages back:

*remote: Submodule 'wordpress' (git://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git) registered for path 'wordpress'*
*remote: Submodule 'wp-content/themes/limeblastevolution/inc/cssCrush' (git://github.com/peteboere/css-crush.git) registered for path 'wp-content/themes/limeblastevolution/inc/cssCrush'*
*remote: fatal: working tree '/srv/www/limeblast.co.uk/htdocs_test' already exists.*
*remote: Clone of 'git://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git' into submodule path 'wordpress' failed*

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You might have success with [git-deploy](https://github.com/mislav/git-deploy).

But if that is too much focused on Rails or if you cannot or will not use it for other reasons, here is how to force a submodule update in a post-commit hook:

```
git submodule init && git submodule sync && git submodule update
```

You must run this on the server; so probably best to add it to your `hooks/post-receive` script. It is simple BASH or SH, bytheway.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've added that line to my post-receive file, but after the initial upload and checkout (which all seem to work fine) I get the error message "remote: You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree." in relation to the submodule stuff. Any ideas? Cheers.