# Git pushing to server

Tags: git

I created a folder called `test.git` on VDS server and make it git repo by running the command `git init --bare`. I pushed a project from my computer to the `test.git` repo on the server. And everything is done successfully. But When I see the `test.git` repo on the server there is nothing. And then I created a empty folder in my computer and cloned the `test.git` repo on the server and the project get back.

In short there is the project in the `test.git` repo on the server but the project is invisible. Why?

Comment: do you have multiple branch created?

Comment: Git doesn't track empty folders as far as I know.  Try adding a file to the folder and then push.

Comment: No there is only master branch

Comment: I pushed a small web project not an empty folder

Comment: What OS is running on your server? How do you "see" the contents of `test.git/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But When I see the test.git repo on the server there is nothing.

Your [Virtual Dedicated Server (VDS)](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/26808/virtual-dedicated-server-vds) should allow you to see the content of `test.git`, [which should be the one typically see in a `.git` folder](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-git-for-real-by-exploring-the-git-directory-1e079c15b807): no working tree, only files for storing the history of your repo, since `test.git` is **[a bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38002059/6309)**.

As I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48415684/6309), making a non-bare repo on your VSD server could work, but is not the best practice.