# Copy modified files git to server folder quickly

Tags: git, shell, ubuntu, copy, shared-directory

I have a Django project and I need a workflow in which my git folder is separated from my server.

In other words:
I am editing files in

```
~/git/web-framework
```

I am running the server (./manage.py runserver) from

```
~/srv/web-framework
```

Currently, I use rsync to update my server folder whenever I change the source code. This takes very long. I think this can be done faster by checking which files are modified with git and then just copying specifically those files to the server location. Can someone help me with a shellscript how to do this? I am running Ubuntu. Or does someone know another faster solution?

Extra information: I am editing all files from my Windows Host machine, while Ubuntu in a VirtualBox is running the server at the same time. If I use the shared folder, the whole server is running incredibly slow (Sharing a folder with VirtualBox just makes it incredibly slow). I want to be able to keep using git commands from windows ánd ubuntu inside this shared folder though.

rsync usually takes up to two minutes

```
real    1m34.494s 
user    0m0.218s 
sys     0m15.264s
```

Furthermore, even when ALL files are up to date it takes long and with the option -vv this might be some relevant information:

```
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0

sent 1,054,073 bytes  received 3,441,985 bytes  42,616.66 bytes/sec
total size is 336,117,027  speedup is 74.76
```

With the command -v, the output says it has done fewer things (still without changes in files):

```
sent 939,612 bytes  received 11 bytes  9,838.98 bytes/sec
total size is 336,117,027  speedup is 357.71
```

During the run, it detects a lot of skipped *.pyc files (because I exclude those) and it has a lot of file x is uptodate messages.

Comment: `rsync` *does* check which files are modified and only transfer those. How slow is slow? What does `rsync` say it is doing and how long does it say it takes?

Comment: Use a git work tree on the server. This will allow the files to be updated the second they're updated on the server. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821825/how-to-set-git-dir-git-work-tree-when-maintaining-multiple-repositories

Comment: @EtanReisner it runs without errors and it takes:
    real 1m34.494s
    user 0m0.218s
    sys 0m15.264s

Will look into git work tree, thanks!

Comment: And how much data is transferred in that time? Does `rsync` give you an indication of where the time is spent?

Comment: @EtanReisner added some detailed output from rsync in the question

Comment: Back-to-back runs of `rsync` without any file changes should report the same amount of work being done (even with `-v` and `-vv` I believe). Can you re-run those tests a few more times without changing any files and alternating `-v` and `-vv` and see if that's true? If, while doing this, you see `rsync` occasionally doing actual work then something is changing your files on you. Also please time all these runs. (I assume they are all about two minutes even when `rsync` reports it does nothing?)