# Error in post-receive hook

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive

I'm trying to implement a work-flow using git.
Here's what I did:

- I have a project on my local (git initialized off course)
- I have added a remote pointing to `xyz`
- I created a directory `xyz` on the server
- Initialized git in `xyz`
- Executed `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch='ignore'` withing `xyz`
  -Afterwards, I created `post-receive` file in `.gt/hooks` and added the following lines:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/xyz
  LOGFILE=./post-receive.log
  cd /path/to/xyz/
  echo "Checking out $PWD"
  echo "Run: checkout dev"
  git checkout dev
  echo "Run: git clean -df & git checkout dev"
  git clean -df & git checkout dev
  echo "Run: git submodule update --init "
  echo "Checking out sumodules"
  git submodule update --init 
  chmod 755 -R /path/to/xyz
  ```

When I `push` using `git push xyz-branch dev --force`, I get the following errors:

```
remote: Checking out /path/to/xyz
remote: Run: checkout dev
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
remote: Run: git clean -df & git checkout dev
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
remote: Run: git submodule update --init 
remote: Checking out sumodules
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
remote: Setting access rights on files and folders
remote: Run: chmod 755 -R /path/to/xyz/
```

I don't know should I blame the docs or myself for mot understanding the cause of the error.

**Update**

I was doing many things wrong.Thanks to a twitter friend who pointed out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635018/reuse-git-work-tree-in-post-receive-hook-to-rm-a-few-files) and I solved my problem. I think it's OK if I explain it as an answer.

Comment: Doesn't `fatal: Not a git repository: '.'` speak for itself? Add a `pwd` after `cd /path/to/xyz/` to see where it ended up. (On a side note, you can use `set -x` instead of all the `echo "Run: ...` lines.)

Comment: ...and on an other side note, you should probably use `set -e` so that if something fails *in* the hook, the hook fails and thus the Git command fails.

Comment: on the 4th line I'm changing to the directory where i have initialized git but still i get `fatal: Not a git repository: '.'` error when `checkout dev` is run

Comment: And are you *sure* there's a Git repo there? What if you run `file .git` after the `cd` (or is it a bare repo?)? I also noticed that `cd` isn't using the `GIT_WORK_TREE` variable; shouldn't it?

Comment: yes there is a git repo, non-bare one.
well, i'm not sure how to utilize `GIT_WORK_TREE' or `GIT_DIR`

Comment: Then may I suggest a Bash scripting tutorial? The quick answer is `cd "$GIT_WORK_TREE"`, but you should probably know such things *before* attempting to write a Git hook. And what about `file .git`?

Comment: Well, I think we learn by doing. :) 

yes .git is there. I have ssh as  well as cpanel access to my site, so i can see whats in the directories. Let me try and update you

Comment: @Biffen `file .git` returns `remote: .git: directory` so it's seeing the .git dir and I'm in the xyz dir.

Comment: Can you make *absolutely* sure the path is correct, and that it's not a matter of absolute vs relative? Did you put the `file` command in the script? Can you "manually" run `git status` in the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to my twitter friend (dotNet and Azure guru) [Ilija](http://www.awsomedevsigner.com/) for pointing me to the right direction. I was able to achieve my goal after reading through the `SO` post I've mentioned in the OP.

Here's what I did:

```
#!/bin/bash
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/xyz
export GIT_DIR=/path/to/xyz/.git
cd $GIT_WORK_TREE 
echo "Checking out dev"
git checkout dev
git clean -df & git checkout dev
unset GIT_WORK_TREE
unset GIT_DIR
echo "Checking out sumodules"
mkdir "codeigniter"
git submodule update --init 
echo "clean"
echo "Setting access rights on files and folders"
echo "Run: chmod 755 -R $GIT_WORK_TREE"
cd "$GIT_WORK_TREE"
chmod 755 -R "$GIT_WORK_TREE"
echo "Done."
```

`export` was the the key to solving my issue.

Please note two `unset` commands.
I ran them as my `repo` has a `submodule`. To have the `submodule` fetch smooth.